# NullPointerException getting collection from MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, multithreading, spring-boot

Here is my problem. I have a Spring Boot application connected to a MongoDB. I created a RESTful API, and using `MongoTemplate` on the *Controllers* did not return any error. But now, I want to create a thread to analyze some data while running the app. The problem es that after that thread is initialized, it returns a `NullPointerException` when the code reaches the statement to connect to the database or to assign the collection to a variable.

The code that returns the error is the following:

```java
public class TreatmentThread implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    MongoCollection<Document> measurements = mongoTemplate.getCollection("measurements");
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            
            List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
                    match(and(
                        gte("date", new java.util.Date(1598464800000L)), 
                        lte("date", new java.util.Date(1598540400000L)))), 
                    sort(orderBy(descending("date"), descending("hour"))), 
                    group(and(eq("device", "$device"), eq("plant", "$plant")), 
                        push("measurements", "$$ROOT")), 
                    project(exclude("measurements._id", "measurements.plant", "measurements.device", "measurements._class")));
            
            AggregateIterable<AnalyzeMeasurements> result = measurements.aggregate(pipeline, AnalyzeMeasurements.class);
            
            // TODO: Analyze results
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.logger.error("Some error ocurred " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

With that code, it returns the error:

> Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.rainforest.eco.analytics.TreatmentThread.(TreatmentThread.java:35)
> at com.rainforest.eco.Application.main(Application.java:25)
> ... 5 more

In case I directly try to get the collection in the code, it simply returns a `NullPointerException`, not giving any more details.

The thread is launched in the `Application.java` class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        
        Log.logger.info("Starting Thread: TreatmentThread");
        Log.logger.info("Starting Thread: Analyze pot measurements to schedule treatments");
        //  Create pool with 10 threads
        int numThreads = 10;
        final ScheduledExecutorService schExService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numThreads);
        // Create runnable thread
        final Runnable treatmentAnalyzer = new TreatmentThread();
        // Thread scheduling
        int minute = 60;
        schExService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(treatmentAnalyzer, minute, 5 * minute, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Log.logger.info("Thread Started: Currently Running");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where the error comes from?

Comment: In the code `TreatmentThread` has been created not in the spring way. You have created the instance of `TreatmentThread` class using the snippet of

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating `TreatmentThread` using a `new` operator doesn't autowire the dependencies. Therefore `MongoTemplate mongoTemplate` is `null` and the subsequent call on it throws the NPE.

You need to autowire such object in the `Application` class as well as define it as a bean (either `@Component` on the class level or `@Bean` on the method level):

```
@Component
public class TreatmentThread implements Runnable {
   ...
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    TreatmentThread treatmentThread;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need to change from the Application code? It is my first time creating a SpringBoot application so I am still getting used to all the dependencies, autowires, etc.
Right now, it returns a error saying it requeries a Bean of type `TreatmentThread`

Comment: @PabloAcereda: Take a look at my edit. I suggest you to start here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested, but it does not seem to work. Now it returns the error `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`.

Comment: I read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire). Although there might have been something I missed. The only changes I implemented were the ones on the answer you edited.